# Modifing generated links from url library in opencart

Tags: php, routes, url-routing, opencart

First lemme tell  you what i am trying to achieve here . Suppose  there is a url  like this `http://www.example.com/?id=12345` now  what i want is if there is an id parameter available in the url i want  to append  the same parameter to every url on that page . Opencart has a url library  that  generates url i am sure you all  must be familiar   with it too  , i found a  way  to do  what i want  but it's  working at just some random parts of the website like categories url's are generating  with id parameter appended to  it and other's  dont .

here's  what  i  tried  so  far

File : System/libray/url.php

here's  the  function

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $connection = 'NONSSL') {
    if ($connection ==  'NONSSL') {
        $url = $this->url;
    }else {
        $url = $this->ssl;  
    }

    $url .= 'index.php?route=' . $route;

    if ($args) {
        $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&')); 
    }

    foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
        $url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        if(!empty($this->request->get['id']))
            $url .= '&id='.$this->request->get['id'];
        if(!empty($_GET['id']))
        {
            $url .= '&id='.$_GET['id'];
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that not everything uses this method to generate its URLs.

For example, anything to do with banners (e.g. the Carousel module) uses links that the admin sets manually in System->Design->Banners, so you would also need to edit the code for this too. The simplest and probably the correct way is to edit the data that the models spit out e.g.

`model_design_banner->getBanner()` becomes

```
public function getBanner($banner_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "banner_image bi LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "banner_image_description bid ON (bi.banner_image_id  = bid.banner_image_id) WHERE bi.banner_id = '" . (int)$banner_id . "' AND bid.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        array_walk($query->rows, function(&$value) {
            $value['link'] .= '&id=' . $_GET['id'];
        });
    }
    return $query->rows;
}
```

It's either that, or edit the output in every single controller that uses this method.

That's just an example for banners, though. I don't recall off-hand which other modules will need to be edited, but if there's a particular one that's making you scratch your head, let me know and I'll give you another example to fix it.

Comment: Hey rj thanks  for  the help  but  i found  out  the  problem was really  not  the code i wrote  but  i  was  getting  the cached output  so  what i  did  is append  the id parameter to every a tag  in the document via  jquery (with validation ofcourse ) ;) , and it's working  perfectly  now .

Comment: Cached output? Sounds odd, these methods don't cache at all. Oh well, as long as you have a solution...

Comment: i know  but   that  particular template  was caching  every output  from database .